# Trying to find the GCD using java. I am stuck on some things with my do while logic

Tags: java

Hello my stack overflow friends. I am working on a simple program for school, requiring me to find the GCD without using %. I am having an isse where it continues to output only

Please enter the first integer:
55
Please enter the second integer:
65
Greatest Common Denominator is:55
Greatest common denominator:10
The GCD of 55and65is 0.

Any tips or hints would be appreciated.

```
package realgcd;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class RealGCD {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int numOne=0;
    int numTwo=0;


    Scanner intOne;
    Scanner intTwo;
    intOne = new Scanner(System.in);
    intTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the first integer:");
    numOne=intOne.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the second integer:");
    numTwo=intTwo.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The GCD of " +numOne+ "and" +numTwo+"is " + getGCD(numOne,numTwo) + ".");
}

public static int getGCD(int numberOne, int numberTwo)
{
   if(numberOne > numberTwo)

    do
    { 
        numberOne-=numberTwo;
    }
   while(numberTwo>0);
   System.out.println("Greatest Common Denominator is:"+numberOne);

   if (numberTwo>numberOne)
   { 
       do 
        {
        numberTwo-=numberOne;
        }
    while (numberTwo>numberOne);
    do 
    {
        numberOne-=numberTwo;
    }   
    while (numberOne>0);
    System.out.println("Greatest common denominator:" +numberTwo);
    }
return 0;

}
}
```

Comment: Your `getGCD` method will always return zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the code yourself from the last System.out.println() in your main method.

The code is going to print a string, but in order to know what the full string is, it has to execute your getGCD() method:

```
System.out.println("The GCD of " +numOne+ "and" +numTwo+"is " + getGCD(numOne,numTwo) + ".");
```

But as the getGCD() method is executed, it prints its own messages to the console.  Once it finally returns (the value of 0 explicitly in all cases), only then does the message from the main method finally get printed to the console.

Your getGCD() method is not working properly. It should compute the GCD of the two given numbers and then return it, rather than trying to print anything to the console.  Then the println statement in the main method will print whatever the getGCD() method returns.

Comment: How would I get it to print the return? I am a bit stuck there.

Comment: @thecommunictycodeguy Here's an example:  

`System.out.println( getNumber() );   // prints "5" to the console`  

`public static int getNumber() { return 5; }`